# React-native: Positioning element based on different simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, android-studio, ios-simulator, styled-components

I have created one Button component by using styled component and typescript. I have used my button in different places. I am currently testing my app into different simulator. I have an issue with positioning the button. In  [iPhone-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWgV4.png) it looks as expected but in  [iPhone-11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfbAp.png) the position of the button is different. I have not tested my app in android yet but I am pretty sure it will look different in Android simulator. I used css properties `top` for positioning. I don't know is there any better way I can position the button component where it looks same in every simulator.

**This is my button component**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import { ButtonText } from '../texts';
import { TouchableOpacityProps } from 'react-native';

type Props = TouchableOpacityProps & {
  title: string;
  onPress: () => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
  endTitle?: string;
  color?: string;
};

const Container = styled.TouchableOpacity<Props>`
  background-color: ${({ theme, disabled, color }) =>
    disabled
      ? theme.colors.greyGradient[500]
      : color ?? theme.colors.primaryGradient[900]};
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: ${({ endTitle }) =>
    endTitle ? 'space-between': 'center'};
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const TitleText = styled(ButtonText)`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
`;

const Button = ({
  title,
  onPress,
  disabled = false,
  endTitle,
  color
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Container
      {...{ title, onPress, disabled, color }}
    >
      <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
      {endTitle && <TitleText>{endTitle}</TitleText>}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**This is the screen where I am using my button component**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


import Button from './Button';

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
`;

const TitleText = styled.Text`
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-horizontal: 20px;
  text-align: center;
`;

const DescriptionText = styled.Text`
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const MenuContainer = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
  top: 23%; // this is the position which is shows me different position in different simulator
`;

const Login = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Container>
      <TitleText>login</TitleText>
      <DescriptionText>Create an account</DescriptionText>
      <MenuContainer>
        <Button
          title="create a new acount"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('register')}
        />
      </MenuContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Post screenshots of the issue you are facing

Comment: I update my question and now you can see the screen shoot

Comment: Using `top: 23%;` is a bad practice to position elements. `%` depends on screen size and hence can create issues like this.

Comment: what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: All I want button component looks same in every simulator.

Comment: can you create a reproducible example using https://snack.expo.io/ ?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@alakdam/shallow-kiwi

Comment: Iphone 8 I used  ` top: 80px;`  then it looks as expected and Iphone 11  ` top: 170px;` then it looks as expected.

Comment: That's the thing, you can't always have this number hardcoded since devices come in various sizes. Instead you should something like `flex: 1` to make the element above this element take the full space, so that this element will always be pushed to the bottom.

Comment: Can you show me in code the solution https://snack.expo.io/@alakdam/shallow-kiwi

Comment: @Krishna. Added an answer, check out if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%` based values on positioning should be avoided since it can cause unforeseen issues on devices with different dimenions.

Instead, you should use `flex: 1` to make an element take up the entire remaining space, so that the element other than this one will get pushed to the edges.

So what you can do is create a new view which has the code for the expandable element.

Like this

```
const Center = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;
```

And put your title and description inside this. Now since I gave it a `flex: 1`, it will try to take as much vertical space as possible.

Now, since your button is below this `Center` element, it will automatically be pushed as much to the bottom as possible.

Check this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@nisanth-reddy/shallow-kiwi) for full code.